# vss-web-extension-sdk package not working with React

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to use vss-web-extension-sdk package with react but its giving me error.
Getting the below error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vss-web-extension-sdk'
```

Comment: Can you add the full output for context as well as the command you're running to get that output?

Comment: Hi Sid, if possible, could you please provide enough information to reproduce the issue? You can remove the in-private information and post it by editing the question.

Comment: try 'npm install vss-web-extension-sdk'